# Tornado script gets response code 500 on live host

Tags: python, ssl, tornado

This script using tornado gets http response code 500 on SOME live hosts. Please don't mind the loop. Its due to oversimplifying my code block. I have tried using the ip but no avail.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tornado
from tornado import httpclient
from tornado import gen
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

gloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

@gen.engine
def process(url):
    print url
    try:
        http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=str(url), connect_timeout=5.0, validate_cert = False, request_timeout=5.0, follow_redirects=True)
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, request)
        print url
        print response.code
        if response.error: raise Exception(response.error)
    except Exception as e:
        print e

gloop.add_callback(process, 'http://www.dhlsameday.com')

tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")
gloop.start()
```

Comment: Just set `validate_cert=False` as param for `HTTPRequest`.

Comment: Done that and now its internal error 500.

Comment: Your script is an HTTP client. You must handle error 5xx and 4xx from the servers.

Comment: thanks matagus, but i should get an HTTPClientResponse from the server shouldn't I? I get the page from a browser but not from this script (on some hosts). tried adding browser agent into the request parameter, but didn't help... :(

Comment: @matagus simply put, using the browser dhlsameday gives 200 but why does the script get a 500?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the untrust cert. At first I suspect is some security to bots, but this website, just, has problems with error handling, it requires `Accept-Language`. Even curl is failing. To get working it simply pass that header:

```
    headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3"}
    request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=str(url), headers=headers, connect_timeout=5.0, validate_cert = False, request_timeout=5.0, follow_redirects=True)
```

I would recommend to add more common browser headers

- Accept
- Accept-Encoding
- Accept-Language
- Connection
- User-Agent (some browser to be not treated as bot)